# AMD Graphics driver Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

Today I tried to connect my secondary screen to my ubuntu 20.10 machine, using the DP connector on the GPU, AMD R9 380.

Due to a faulty cable I got some glitches on the screen... The first thing that came to mind was to update the drivers with the ones from AMD website. I've tried to install the 20.04 ones but didn't work. After that I uninstalled everything and now I cannot get the old drivers back.

If I go to About section in the Settings at the GPU I have `llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits)`

I cannot change the resolution, refresh rate or anything related to display settings.

How can I revert all and use the AMD drivers that came preinstalled or any other drivers that may let me use the GPU properly?

Comment: `llvmpipe` indicates that you're using the fallback open-source driver, instead of the proprietary drivers that AMD provides on their website. Try this link: https://forum.level1techs.com/t/ubuntu-20-10-rx-6800-xt-how-to-steam-vulkan-up-and-runing-guide-wip/164137 . Good luck!

Comment: @wyphan thanks, that solved the issue